# PHP / PDO - Error message form doesn't appear

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't appear my error messages from a registration form. The error messages are Javascript pop-ups for the moment but i want to illustrate my errors into the MySQL database.

> ```
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE USE_USERNAME = :username AND USE_EMAIL = :email AND USE_PASSWORD = :password";
> //Requête permettAnt de récupérer toutes les données des utilisateurs actuels du site pour pouvoir établir
> //les conditions ci-dessous.
> ```

```
$request = $db->prepare($sql);
$request->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$request->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$request->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$request->execute();
while ($row = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($username == $row['USE_USERNAME']) {
        $error++;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Erreur#5 : Pseudonyme déjà dans base !");  //Cas dans lequel les identifiants sont incorrects.
            document.location.href = "subscribe.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    } else if ($email == $row['USE_EMAIL']) {
        $error++;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Erreur#5 : Email Faux!");  //Cas dans lequel les identifiants sont incorrects.
            document.location.href = "subscribe.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I put the "UNIQUE" Constraint for the Email and the Username for example but i had a WAMP error when i tried to insert an email and it's normal, but i only want to appear the popups.

Sorry for my english, i don't speak very well but if you need more details, i'm here :)

Thanks for your help :)

Ah ! I forgot the insert query.

```
            //Insertion des données de l'utilisateur
            $request = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (USE_USERNAME, USE_EMAIL, USE_PASSWORD) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)");
            $request->bindParam(":username", $username);
            $request->bindParam(":email", $email);
            $request->bindParam(":password", $pass_hache);
            $request->execute();
        }
            ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and get the *real* errors as to why your code is failing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for the documentation :) But, i corrected my Try/Catch for the mySQL database connection and the problem always was there.